# How to make pulse wave from sine wave - audio frequency

Tags: pulse, sine, trigger, distortion

I'm looking for a quick-and-dirty way of converting something close to a sine wave to a narrow pulse wave. Please see the image: a low bass note played through a broken transformer. I'm trying to re-create the effect, preferably using discrete components.

[image: narrow pulse waveform]

Comment: try 'Low pass filter + zero crossing comparator'.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of some sort of a zero crossing detector. But I'm not good at designing circuits and I haven't really found a simple low voltage one (preferably with transistor(s)).

Comment: It is very important to perform lowpass filtering (integration) prior to zero-crossing detection.

Comment: OK thank you! I found this circuit, a good one to start with?  http://sound.westhost.com/appnotes/an005-f1.gif

Comment: You show an output waveform and clearly there are pulses but what is the stuff in-between - is it noise that you don't want or part of the input signal? Are the pulses coincident with a certain part of the input waveform i.e. zero cross of input or possibly the peak voltage? Are there in fact many pulses per cycle? I cannot tell because I can't see the input waveform.

Comment: Part of the noise is probably vinyl rumble but part of it is bass waveform. It's quite possibly the peak voltage, one pulse per cycle. I can get something a bit similar with a mis-biased transistor, but nothing that symmetrical.  You can hear the sound here, starting at 1:26 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2WBBcH6OPU

Comment: I did some filtering of the signal and it looks like there a strong spike at (the peak of ?) each cycle.

Comment: The low pass/ zero crossing / compartor will give pulses. If you want bipolar pulses, then maybe turn it into a square wave and differentiate that.  (A high pass filter to catch only the edges.... this will give pulses at twice the input frequency.  If that's what you want?  (you could make the square wave with a comparator, or gain up the signal till it clips.. assuming the amplifier doesn't mind.

Answer (score -4):

There is a way to convert a cosine and sine waves into a pulse. I do this in RF.

First of all you have to have both real and imaginary waves. We start with just a real wave and then perform a complex multiply. After some digital filtering you get both real and imaginary waves. For my project there are about 2 or 3 cycles at some frequency.

From trigonometry, cosine^2 + sine^2 = 1;

Your perform this equation on each sample.

This will give you a pulse.